# Laravel Check If Related Model Exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an Eloquent model which has a related model:

```
public function option() {
    return $this->hasOne('RepairOption', 'repair_item_id');
}

public function setOptionArrayAttribute($values)
{
    $this->option->update($values);
}
```

When I create the model, it does not necessarily have a related model. When I update it, I might add an option, or not.

So I need to check if the related model exists, to either update it, or create it, respectively:

```
$model = RepairItem::find($id);
if (Input::has('option')) {
    if (<related_model_exists>) {
        $option = new RepairOption(Input::get('option'));
        $option->repairItem()->associate($model);
        $option->save();
        $model->fill(Input::except('option');
    } else {
       $model->update(Input::all());
    }
};
```

Where `<related_model_exists>` is the code I am looking for.

Comment: Awesome question thank you!  And great answers to the guys below.  Saved me time on my project.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

In **php 7.2+** you can't use `count` on the relation object, so there's no one-fits-all method for all relations. Use query method instead as @tremby provided below:

```
$model->relation()->exists()
```

---

generic solution working on all the relation types (**pre php 7.2**):

```
if (count($model->relation))
{
  // exists
}
```

This will work for every relation since dynamic properties return `Model` or `Collection`. Both implement `ArrayAccess`.

So it goes like this:

**single relations:** `hasOne` / `belongsTo` / `morphTo` / `morphOne`

```
// no related model
$model->relation; // null
count($model->relation); // 0 evaluates to false

// there is one
$model->relation; // Eloquent Model
count($model->relation); // 1 evaluates to true
```

**to-many relations:** `hasMany` / `belongsToMany` / `morphMany` / `morphToMany` / `morphedByMany`

```
// no related collection
$model->relation; // Collection with 0 items evaluates to true
count($model->relation); // 0 evaluates to false

// there are related models
$model->relation; // Collection with 1 or more items, evaluates to true as well
count($model->relation); // int > 0 that evaluates to true
```

Comment: Doesn't a `Collection` already have a `count()` function? So you could just say `$model->relation->count()`?

Comment: Read whole thing. `count($relation)` is a general solution for all relations. It will work for `Model` and `Collection`, while `Model` has no `->count()` method.

Comment: @CurvianVynes Not, it doesn't. `Collection` has its own method `isEmpty`, but generic `empty` function returns false for an object (thus won't work for empty collection).

Comment: `count($model->relation)` didn't work on `morphTo` when relationship had no association set yet. Foreign id and type are null and the db query built by Laravel is bogus and rises exception. I used `$model->relation()->getOtherKey()` as a workaround.

Comment: @Jocelyn Yes, it's Eloquent bug. Unfortunately there are at least a few of them for polymorphic relations, so obviously you can't rely on them in any way.

Comment: count() fails if both (or more) relations, model->relationa->relationb do not exist. So I check each with count() first.

Comment: Important question, if you are lazy loading `$model->relation`, does `count($model->relation)` actually query and load all data for the related model?  Wouldn't `$model->relation()->value('id')` be better for performance in that case?

Comment: @CaptainHypertext to be precise - `value('id')` is going to fail for pivot relations, so I'd rather use `exists()`. As for the question - that depends. It will run the query and load the relation indeed, so if you don't care about the relation itself, but only the fact whether it exists, then it's better.

Comment: In blade templates this doesn't work. So I used a model method: public function isOptionLoaded() { count($this->relations['option']); }

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk it was normal \@if($model->isOptionLoaded()) do this \@else do that \@endif

Comment: `$this->relations['option']` is brittle - it will cause error if you don't load the relation. The `count($model->relation)` works for sure

Comment: Any suggestions for how to do this in PHP 7.2 where this errors out if null?

Comment: A hasOne relation might return null and `count(null)` throws an exception in PHP 7.1 so this is not the generic solution.

Comment: It will break on PHP 7.2, returning: `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Comment: For single-model-relations, a count() isn't even necessary. Just `if ($model->relation)` is enough.

Comment: @CodeGodie +1 also, even if it works for < PHP 7.2, I strongly disagree with calling `count()` on an object that isn't logically "countable"

Comment: @andrewtweber it is perfectly fine to disagree with different opinions, especially a few years old +1

Answer (score 101):

A [Relation object](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.html) passes unknown method calls through to an [Eloquent query Builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html), which is set up to only select the related objects. That Builder in turn passes unknown method calls through to *its* underlying [query Builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html).

This means you can use the [`exists()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists) or [`count()`](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_count) methods directly from a relation object:

```
$model->relation()->exists(); // bool: true if there is at least one row
$model->relation()->count(); // int: number of related rows
```

Note the parentheses after `relation`: `->relation()` is a function call (getting the relation object), as opposed to `->relation` which a magic property getter set up for you by Laravel (getting the related object/objects).

Using the `count` method on the relation object (that is, using the parentheses) will be much faster than doing `$model->relation->count()` or `count($model->relation)` (unless the relation has already been eager-loaded) since it runs a count query rather than pulling all of the data for any related objects from the database, just to count them. Likewise, using `exists` doesn't need to pull model data either.

Both `exists()` and `count()` work on all relation types I've tried, so at least `belongsTo`, `hasOne`, `hasMany`, and `belongsToMany`.

Comment: exists is not available in lumen, not sure why.

Comment: @briankip -- it should. You sure you're getting the relation object (by calling the method) rather than the collection (by using the magic property)?

Comment: At least in Laravel 6.x, `exists` doesn't work for a `morphTo` relationship that doesn't exist. It gets a SQL error.

Comment: Keep in mind that calling `exists()` and `count()` on the relationship requires that the related model already be saved in the database. If you need to check for existence before the related model has been saved (for example, if you used setRelation), then you should use `is_null` or `empty`.

Comment: When we are using Query Builder we can't access to relations we defined at Model :(

Comment: @OrmanFaghihiMohaddes: the text in my answer about the query builder is just part of an explanation of how this works. You're accessing a query builder via the relation you defined on the model, so yes you absolutely still are using the relations you defined on the model.

Answer (score 23):

I prefer to use `exists` method:

`RepairItem::find($id)->option()->exists()`

to check if related model exists or not. It's working fine on Laravel 5.2

Comment: +1; count($model->relation) was returning true for me in Laravel 5.2 even though there was no item in the relation table. ->exists() does the trick.

Answer (score 17):

After **Php 7.1**, The accepted answer won't work for all types of relationships.

Because depending of type the relationship, Eloquent will return a `Collection`, a `Model` or `Null`. And in **Php 7.1** `count(null)` will throw an `error`.

So, to check if the relation exist you can use:

For relationships single: For example `hasOne` and `belongsTo`

```
if(!is_null($model->relation)) {
   ....
}
```

For relationships multiple: For Example: `hasMany` and `belongsToMany`

```
if ($model->relation->isNotEmpty()) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! If I eager-loaded relations and executed a ->count() in a foreach loop of results, even if they were eager-loaded in the model, it would generate an SQL query for each items. Using !is_null($model->relation) is the fastest and SQL friendly way to do it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

I use for single relationships: `hasOne`, `belongsTo` and `morphs`

```
if($model->relation){ 
 ....
}
```

Because if condition is null, this will be false.

For multiple relationships: `hasMany`, `belongsToMany` and `morphs`

```
if ($model->relation->isNotEmpty()) {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [relationLoaded](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L3239) method on the model object. This saved my bacon so hopefully it helps someone else. I was [given this suggestion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/testing-for-existence-of-relational-data) when I asked the same question on Laracasts.

Answer (score 4):

As Hemerson Varela already said in Php 7.1 `count(null)` will throw an `error` and `hasOne` returns `null` if no row exists. Since you have a `hasOne`relation I would use the `empty` method to check:

```
$model = RepairItem::find($id);
if (!empty($temp = $request->input('option'))) {
   $option = $model->option;

   if(empty($option)){
      $option = $model->option()->create();
   }

   $option->someAttribute = temp;
   $option->save();
};
```

But this is superfluous. There is no need to check if the relation exists, to determine if you should do an `update` or  a `create` call. Simply use the [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method. This is equivalent to the above:

```
$model = RepairItem::find($id);
if (!empty($temp = $request->input('option'))) {  
   $model->option()
         ->updateOrCreate(['repair_item_id' => $model->id],
                          ['option' => $temp]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this has changed in Laravel 5, but the accepted answer using `count($data->$relation)` didn't work for me, as the very act of accessing the relation property caused it to be loaded.

In the end, a straightforward `isset($data->$relation)` did the trick for me.

Comment: I believe it is `$data->relation` without `$` (can't edit, because of 6 characters limit)

Comment: Ah the `$relation` would be the name of your relation, such as `$data->posts` or such like. Sorry if that was confusing, I wanted to make it clear that `relation` wasn't a concrete model property :P

Comment: This was working for a while, but it stopped working after I updated Laravel from 5.2.29 to 5.2.45. Any idea why or how to fix it? It's now causing the relational data to be loaded for some reason.

Comment: I added an answer that has a fix for this.

Comment: This won't work in more recent versions of Laravel. Since at least Laravel 5.8, the `Model::__isset` method is overloaded such that it returns true even if there is no related entity. You'll need to use `!is_null` to avoid the magic `isset` logic. They have confirmed that this is a known bug in Laravel that will be fixed in Laravel 8: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31793

Answer (score 1):

I had to completely refactor my code when I updated my PHP version to 7.2+ because of bad usage of the count($x) function. This is a real pain and its also extremely scary as there are hundreds usages, in different scenarios and there is no one rules fits all..

Rules I followed to refactor everything, examples:

**$x = Auth::user()->posts->find(6);** (check if user has a post id=6 using ->find())

```
[FAILS] if(count($x)) { return 'Found'; } 
[GOOD] if($x) { return 'Found'; }
```

**$x = Auth::user()->profile->departments;** (check if profile has some departments, there can have many departments)

```
[FAILS] if(count($x)) { return 'Found'; }
[GOOD] if($x->count()) { return 'Found'; }
```

**$x = Auth::user()->profile->get();** (check if user has a profile after using a ->get())

```
[FAILS] if(count($x)) { return 'Found'; }
[GOOD] if($x->count()) { return 'Found'; }
```

Hopes this can help, even 5 years after the question has been asked, this stackoverflow post has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the model class and use Eloquent ORM, then create a new method and return bool data. like

```
public function hasPosts(): bool
{
    return $this->posts()->exists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RelationLoaded](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_relationLoaded) method of Model class could be useful.

```
if ($this->relationLoaded('prices')) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but in each case your project version may not be taken into account. Be careful.

Either you use the `relationLoaded()` method as shown in the following example

```
$user = User::find(1);
if ($user->relationLoaded('posts')) {
    // The "posts" relation is loaded for this user
}
```

You can use the `has()` method

```
$user->has('posts');
```

you can use the method `exists()`

```
if ($user->posts()->exists()) {
    // The user has associated articles ("posts" relationship)
}
```

you can also use the `method_exists()` function
$user = new User;

```
if (method_exists($user, 'posts')) {
     // The model has a "posts" relationship method
}
```

Note, once again, that in each case, the version of your project may not be taken into account.