# Laravel - How to check if One To One relationship exists?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have 2 models: Car, Driver.

Car model:

```
<?php

class Car extends \Eloquent {
    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Driver');
    }
}
```

Driver model:

```
<?php

class Driver extends \Eloquent {
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Car');
    }
}
```

How to query one or all cars that don't belong to any driver yet?
How to check whether queried car belongs to any driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent way:

```
$driverlessCars = Car::has('driver', '=', 0)->get();
// Collection of Car models
```

For more info check this out: [Laravel check if related model exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exist#answer-23911985)