# Troubles with Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm rather new to Eloquent (and ORM's as a whole really). I have done rather a lot of background reading but can't quite get my head around the relationships in Eloquent.

I have a Car model that relates to a Color model, a Make model and a Model model.

I pass my Car::getAll() through to my View as $cars. When I call dd(toArray($cars)) I get the following:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'registration' => string '123' (length=3)
      'make' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Ford' (length=4)
          'slug' => string 'ford' (length=4)
          'created_at' => string '2014-06-26 21:30:23' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2014-06-26 21:30:23' (length=19)
      'model' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Mustang' (length=7)
          'slug' => string 'mustang' (length=7)
          'created_at' => string '2014-06-26 21:30:41' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2014-06-26 21:30:41' (length=19)
      'color' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Red' (length=3)
          'slug' => string 'red' (length=3)
          'created_at' => string '2014-06-26 21:30:03' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2014-06-26 21:30:03' (length=19)
      'year' => string '1991' (length=4)
      'is_classic' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => string '999.00' (length=6)
      'sold' => string '0' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_at' => string '2014-06-26 22:17:27' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-06-26 22:17:27' (length=19)`
```

Which appears to be right to me, however when I have:

```
foreach ($cars as $car) {
  echo $car->color-title;
}
```

I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

My Models are as follows:

**Car.php**

```
class Car extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['color_id'];


    public function color() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Color', 'id');
    }

    public function model() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Model', 'id');
    }

    public function make() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Make', 'id');
    }

    public static function getAll() {
        return Car::with('color', 'make', 'model')->where('active', 1)->get();
    }
}
```

**Color.php**

```
class Color extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug'];

    public function cars() {
        return $this->hasMany('Car', 'color');
    }
}
```

**Make.php**

```
class Make extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function cars() {
        return $this->hasMany('Car', 'make');
    }
}
```

**Model.php**

```
class Model extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function cars() {
        return $this->hasMany('Car', 'model');
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT:**

Sorry I should have included my schema up methods:

**CreateMakesTable**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('makes', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**CreateModelsTable**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('models', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('make')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('models', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('make')->references('id')->on('makes')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**CreateColorsTable**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('colors', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**CreateCarsTable**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('registration');
            $table->integer('make')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('model')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->integer('color')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('is_classic');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->boolean('sold');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->timestamps();
         });

         Schema::table('cars', function(Blueprint $table)
         {
            $table->foreign('make')->references('id')->on('makes')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('model')->references('id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('color')->references('id')->on('colors')->onDelete('cascade');
         });
    }
```

Comment: Where are foreign keys? Those relation definitions are wrong, that's for sure.

Comment: You should never assume a relationship exists inside a loop. You probably have a car without a related color model being returned. Check first, then do whatever you need to do.

Comment: @deczo I have added my Schema up methods to show where foreign keys are.

Comment: @JasonLewis Sorry, could you point me in the direction of how to check this? I presumed by being able to return it as an array like this it showed I had the object as expected - although clearly it doesn't :/

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason pointed out the error is caused by `null` returned from one of those relationships. But the problem with your setup is, that the relationship definitions are wrong.

So first make them right:

```
// it goes like this:
// belongsTo('Model', 'foreign_key_on_this_model', 'primary_key_on_related')

public function color() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Color', 'color'); // primary key is id so no need to specify
}
```

`hasMany` relations on the other models are OK.

Then in that loop:

```
foreach ($cars as $car)
{
   if (count($car->color))
   {
       // do something with color
   }
}
```

For the reason I'm using `count` read this: [Laravel check if related model exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists#answer-23911985)

You can also return only cars that have related color, make and whatever you need like below:

```
$cars = Car::has('color')->has('make')...
```