# How can I use laravel db query ->update() method in if statement

Tags: laravel

I want to check something in if, and if that condition is true I want to update the record that was fetched before.

```
$resultQuery = DB::table('cards')->where('api_id', $card->id)->first();

if (this condition will pass I want to update this record) {
    $resultQuery->update(array('price_usd' => $card->prices->usd));
}
```

When I use the ->update() like this, I get an error:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::update();

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

The `first()` function on laravel query builder returns a `stdClass` meaning **Standard Class**.

There is no function called `update()` in `stdClass` in php. You have called `update()` on stdClass, and that causes the error.

There are several ways to achieve your goal.

1. Use Laravel query builder `update()` function.

```php
$resultQuery = DB::table('cards')->where('api_id', $card->id)->first();

if (your_condition) {
    Db::table('cards')
        ->where('api_id', $card->id)
        ->update([
            'price_usd' => $card->prices->usd
        ]);
}
```

2. If you don't want to fetch the card data, don't call `first()`

```php
$resultQuery = DB::table('cards')->where('api_id', $card->id);

if (your_condition) {
    $resultQuery
        ->update([
             'price_usd' => $card->prices->usd
        ]);
}
```

3. Use Eloquent models (Laravel's preferred way)

Create an Eloquent model for Cards (if you have not done already).

```php
public class Card extends Model
{

}
```

Use eloquent query builder to fetch data. And use model `update()` function to update data.

```php
$resultingCard = Card::where('api_id', $card->id)->first();

if (your_condition) {
    $resultingCard->update([
        'price_usd' => $card->prices->usd,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$resultQuery = DB::table('cards')->where('api_id', $card->id);

if ($resultQuery->count()) {

  $object = $resultQuery->first();
  $object->price_usd = $card->prices->usd;
  $object->save();
}
```

Or look for an alternative solutions here: [Eloquent ->first() if ->exists()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531312/eloquent-first-if-exists)

Comment: He has not mentioned his condition, It may __not__ be about the result. Except that, your answer is almost correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using model

You can add in card controller

```php
$card = Card::where('api_id', $card->id)->first();

if (someConditional) 
{
  // Use card properties, number is a example.
  $card->number = 10
  // This line update this card.
  $card->save();
}
```

You can learn more about [eloquent here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent).