# Laravel 4 - Finding out if an M:N relation exists between 2 models

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 models, one is a *Poll*, and another is an *User*. I have set up a M:N relationship between both of them:

*User.php*

```
public function votedPolls() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Polls', 'votes');
}
```

*Poll.php*

```
public function voters() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'votes');
}
```

And it all works nicely. When I vote on a poll, the table `votes` get populated properly. But now I want to check inside the controller if a user has already voted in a poll.

I figured it would be something like this, but I am not sure of the syntax. I tried this (which does **not** work):

```
$voters = $poll->voters()->where('id', '=', $user->id)->first();
$voted = count($voters) == 1;
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists#answer-23911985

Comment: I dont see how that helps my problem...

Comment: That tells me if a relationship exists, but wont tell me if the objects of the model have a relationship stablished?

Comment: Why the code you tried does not work exactly? I assume you need to use `where('users.id','=',$user->id)` because pivot table also has `id` column, just a guess.

Comment: That was it! Put it on an answer, and Ill give you the credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is preferred way of checking if relations exist.

Your code didn't work because your pivot table also has `id` column and `where` clause was ambiguous, so change it to:

```
where('users.id','=',$user->id)
```