# Laravel pivot tables n:m relationships

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have table `organisations` and another table `clients`. An organisation can have many clients, and a client can belong to many organisations hence the many-to-many relationship and the pivot table `client_organisation`.

In my model `Organisation.php` I have the following,

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

    //Organisation __has_many__ clients
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('client');
    }

}
```

and in my `Client.php` model I have,

```
class Client extends Eloquent {

    public function organisations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('organisation');
    }

}
```

The Pivot table migration,

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateClientOrganisationTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('client_organisation', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('organisation_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('organisation_id')->references('id')->on('organisations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('client_organisation');
    }

}
```

I then run the following in my controller, to retrieve all the organisations and there clients,

```
$organisations = new Organisation;  
$organisations->clients()->get();
```

however this results in the following error,

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'clients.organisation_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `clients` where `clients`.`organisation_id` is null)

Now it is my understanding that should not need a `clients.organisation_id` column in my database as I have a pivot table, what am I doing wrong? I want to be able to get all my organisations and their clients, using the pivot table.

Comment: `clients` relationship should be `belongsToMany` instead of `hasMany`

Comment: changed but still the query is looking for `'clients.organisation_id'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a pivot table, you should use `belongsToMany` on both ends of the relationship:

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Client');
    }

}

class Client extends Eloquent {

    public function organisations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation');
    }

}
```

Note that the first argument to `belongsToMany` is the name of the class, which is capitalized.

Comment: Ah excellent that gets rid of the error, but returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )` I was expecting an object of organisations and clients

Comment: The reason is that the class names are used. `Client` and `Organisation` in the relations.

Comment: @Cycs - Exactly what code are you writing and what are you expecting instead?

Comment: What should I use then? The table names?

Comment: @JosephSilber I am expecting an object containing my organisations and nested in each organisation another object container it's clients

Comment: @Cycs - That's exactly what you got: a collection of your objects. What else do you want?

Comment: Then why is it seemingly empty, I have 1 organisation, and they has 1 client. Maybe I am confused, should I not be able to do, `$organisations = new Organisation;  $org = $organisations->projects()->get()` and then die(print_r($org)) and see an object? not `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: @Cycs - How do you intend to load relationships to an entry that doesn't exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58800/discussion-between-cycs-and-joseph-silber).

Comment: I would assume it would return null values for organisations that have no clients?

Comment: @Cycs Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists#answer-23911985

Comment: Looks like this is a misunderstanding.  Try `$org = $organisations->projects()->get()->toArray()` and then dump that.  It should show you the array.  Dumping the collection won't actually show all the items in the collection.