# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need a little clarification.

This error message "Trying to get property of non-object" to what is referred to when using Eloquent? I'm going crazy. I am using a function:

```
public function squadra_post()
{
return $this->hasMany('Squadra','id_squadra');
}
```

that is the model that extends Eloquent Post. When the call:

```
<?php $squadra = Post::find($roles->id_squadra)->squadra_post; ?>
```

gives me the error that I mentioned before.

**EDIT**

his is the class post with their methods. What to give problems is "squadra_post ()" I need to extract the name of the team by id_squadra post content in table.

```
class Post extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
    protected $table = 'post';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_post';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function commenti() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Commento','id_post');
    }

    public function apprezzamenti() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Apprezzamenti','id_post');
    }   

    public function squadra_post() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Squadra','id_squadra');
    } 
}
```

This is the code of the class "squadra"

```
class Squadra extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
    protected $table = 'squadra';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_squadra';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

And finally, this is the code that gives me problems. That is what gives me the error: Trying to get property of non-object

```
@foreach($post['post'] as $roles)
    @if($roles->id_squadra != 0)
        $squadra = Post::find($roles->id_squadra)->squadra_post;
        @foreach($squadra as $squadra_post)
           {{ $squadra->nome }}
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
$squadra = Post::find($roles->id_squadra)->squadra_post;
```

the `squadra_post()` method

returns a collection of objects (posts I guess) and not an object because of the nature of your relationship (1 to many) while `Post::find()` returns the object. I think this is where the error occurs.

try the following code

```
 $squadra = Post::find($roles->id_squadra); 

 if ($squadra) {
   echo $squadra->name;

  foreach ($squadra->squadra_post as $post) {
       echo $post->title;
       echo $post->content; //etc
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also you'll have to be sure that the foreign key is the `id_squadra` that you declare in your `squadra_post()` method.

Comment: I've already tried, but I have always the same error. The thing I do not understand is that I use a similar code with "like" and comments and that's fine.

Comment: Are you sure that $roles->id_squadra is returning a single id and not multiple?

Comment: It gives me this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I'm sorry

"Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: If you change $roles->id_squadra with an existing id you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

When you tired attempting to find the particular post, it couldn't find it and hence it is throwing an exception saying "Trying to get property of non-object". If it had found the post, it would have returned the squadra_post and it would have been stored in the variable.

But instead it could not find that particular and could not construct an object with it and hence it could not find that particular property name squadra_post. Therefore the error "Trying to get property of non-object".

You could handle this exception by putting the code in a try and catch block.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your relation won't work this way, becuase **Laravel 4+ expects relation names to be `camelCased`** and only then you can use [dynamic properties](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#dynamic-properties).

So rename it to `squadraPost()`and call like `$post->squadraPost`, and in case of `hasMany` you will get a `Collection` here, no matter if there is any related model or not.

Next thing is **checking if related model exists** - for this read the answer here: [Laravel check if related model exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists)

And last, but not least: **you may get `null` from `find()` method**, so first make sure this:

```
$post = Post::find(..)
```

returns your model, not `null`. Only then can you call its relation:

```
if ($post) $post->squadraPost;
```