# laravel check if relation between multiple tables exsist

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables:

```
Table_A
  - id
  - sth

Table_B
  - id
  - a_id
  - sth

Table_C
  - id
  - b_id
  - sth

Table_D
  - id
  - c_id
  - sth
```

The relationships are as followed

```
Table_A <- Table_B (One to Many)
Table_B <- Table_C (One to Many)
Table_C <- Table_D (One to Many)
```

In order to access `Table_C` and `Table_D` from `Table_A` I used a `hasManyThrough` relationship for `C` and `D`. So now I pass `a_id`, `b_id` and `c_id` on GET because and I want to check if the relation between them exists.

First I tried this:

`Table_A::with('Table_B.Table_C.Table_D')`

The problem is I don't know how I can pass ids for each of the tables and I'm not sure if it will work, I would like to know if this can work or if there is a better way to check these relationships exist.

Comment: You should be able to check the relationship easily with Eloquent. `$model->relationship->count()` or `count($model->relationship)`.

Comment: For your problem there should be something on Laravel to solve your problem in efficient way. But a way that i can think right now is fetching via table A. `count($table_a_data->table_b)` and then if count positive then `count ($table_a_data->table_b->table_c)` and `count($table_a_data->table_b->table_c->table_d)`. This will work for proper relationship. But the thing is this will increase your execution time if you have operations for each record in a relation.

Comment: @HelloSpeakman yes you are right, I was thinking the same but think if we have operations associated with each one to many relation records then this will go exponential complexity.

Comment: It sounds smart. I will check and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel check if related model exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists)

Comment: It works ;), it was so easy... Thanks once again.