# Laravel 8: Can I make Eloquent scope but NOT against query builder but against related model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model - let's call it `Parent`.

Each `Parent` can have many children.

```
public function children(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Child::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

I want to make a scope for `Parent` called "active".

My requirement goes as follows:

> Parent is active when it has at least 1 child.

I've done local scopes multiple times and I know that within `Parent.php` I can do something like:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where(…);
}
```

But as you see, `$query` is a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` which is not my case. I want to operate on related model somehow, not the DB query.

Can I do this in a clean way without fetching all parents `with('child')` and within `->filter()` forgetting those that have no children? When there will be 1000 parents but only one will have children, it will simply waste DB resources (by fetching 999 redundant parents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->has('children');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicklas, this is a clean solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `whereHas` in scope:

```
public function scopeActive($query){
  return $query->whereHas('children');
}
```

OR

```
public function scopeActive(){
  return $this->whereHas('children');
}
```

And

```
Parent::active()->with('children')->get();
```

should give you all Parents who have children and along with respective children

Comment: `whereHas()` takes 2 arguments, the relationship name and a function to use, like `whereHas('children', function ($subQuery) { $subQuery->where(...); }));`; this answer has the right idea, but the wrong implementation. Should just be `has()` (as one of the other answers shows)

Comment: @TimLewis, isnt the callback argument optional? 
Edit: (it is optional, and it actually uses `has` method. I think this implementation would work equally well) https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L144

Comment: Huh, well there you go! I thought for sure it was a required param, but verified in a local install against a couple Laravel versions; it is indeed optional. Good on you for demonstrating an optional, more flexible solution. Cheers!

Comment: Cool of you to verify. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like:

```php
public function getActiveAttribute() {
  return $this->children()->count() > 1;
}
```

This can be used like,

```php
$parent->active
```

And the query will only be made when you'll try to access the `active` property on the `Parent` model, not when you will be fetching all parents.

Answer (score -1):

In Parent

```
public function getActiveAttribute() {
  return $this-> children()->exists();
}
```

In code

```
$parent = new Parent;
if($parent->active){//true}
```

You can also use count

count($this->children); // 0 evaluates to false

a related thread here if you need:
[Laravel Check If Related Model Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910553/laravel-check-if-related-model-exists)